# How do I hide file extensions from showing up by default in TortoiseHg commit?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHg to commit files to my repository; however, it shows all the .pyc files by default. Is it possible to exclude these files from being shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Mercurial ignore those files by writing something like the following in your `.hgignore` file (which should be placed at the same level as your `.hg` directory):

```
# use glob syntax.
syntax: glob

*.pyc
```

After doing that you'll want to remove the existing `.pyc` files (using the `hg rem` command).